# Python program that simulates a full one player game of pig, starting at a totalscore of 0 and playing turn after turn until it reaches 100 points

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability, dice

So here is a sample output:

     `- rolled a 2
     - rolled a 1
     Pigged out!
     Turn score = 0
     New total score = 0
     - rolled a 1
     Pigged out!
     Turn score = 0
     New total score = 0
     - rolled a 6
     - rolled a 6
     - rolled a 6
     - rolled a 5
     Turn score = 23 #So on
     New total score = 90
     - rolled a 6
     - rolled a 6
     - rolled a 3
     Turn score = 15
     New total score = 105`

And here is how I tried to solve it:

```
`    import random
     print("Well, hello there.")
     score = 0
     while(score<=100):
         turn_score=0
         while (turn_score<=20):
             dice_value=random.randint(1,6)
             if (dice_value==1):
                 print("Pigged out! Better luck next time!")
                 turn_score=0
                 break #to get out of the loop in case a roll rolls up
             else:
                 print("-rolled a ",dice_value)
                 score+=dice_value 
                 print("Score is  ",turn_score)
        score+=turn_score
        print("Final score is: ",score)`
```

What I tried doing is first making an inner loop that will roll the dice, add the values(except if a 1 comes up, in which case the turn score would be 0) and present it as the turn score.

Then I thought of looping it as a whole till a total turn score of >=100 is reached.

Can someone explain where I went wrong here?

Here is the output I get when I run it: 

`Well, hello there.
-rolled a  3
Score is   0
-rolled a  2
Score is   0
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
Pigged out! Better luck next time!
Final score is:  11
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
-rolled a  4
Score is   0
-rolled a  5
Score is   0
-rolled a  2
Score is   0
-rolled a  2
Score is   0
-rolled a  4
Score is   0
-rolled a  2
Score is   0
-rolled a  3
Score is   0
-rolled a  4
Score is   0
-rolled a  4
Score is   0
Pigged out! Better luck next time!
Final score is:  47
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
-rolled a  5
Score is   0
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
-rolled a  5
Score is   0
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
Pigged out! Better luck next time!
Final score is:  75
-rolled a  3
Score is   0
-rolled a  2
Score is   0
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
-rolled a  4
Score is   0
-rolled a  2
Score is   0
Pigged out! Better luck next time!
Final score is:  98
-rolled a  6
Score is   0
-rolled a  4
Score is   0
-rolled a  2
Score is   0
-rolled a  3
Score is   0
Pigged out! Better luck next time!
Final score is:  113`

Comment: `while score<=100:` this will draw another roll if `score == 100` you rather use `while score < 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `else` block, change

```
score+=dice_value
```

to

```
turn_score += dice_value
```

You're never incrementing turn_score at any point in the loop, so the while loop is only ever ending when it rolls a 1 and hits the `break` statement. Additionally, with that line in place, you're adding to `score` on turns that would pig out, which isn't supposed to happen.